# Como compilar o gettext no MSYS2 usando x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc

Tags: compilação, gcc, make, msys2

Eu estou fazendo uma série de recompilações para montar um QEMU personalizado para meus estudos de microcontrolador, tive sucesso na compilação de alguns pacotes até o gettext, depois de ler todos os arquivos de instrução em seu diretório e buscar na internet conselhos e dicas, além de ler scripts que aparentemente seria um sucesso ainda não consegui passar do make.

Segui os seguintes passos

```
git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/gettext.git
cd gettext
git checkout v0.19.8.1
GNULIB_SRCDIR=../gnulib \
        GNULIB_TOOL=../gnulib-tool \
        ./autogen.sh
mkdir build
cd build
../configure \
    --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 \
    --prefix=/mingw64 \
    --with-gnu-ld \
    --without-bzip2 \
    --without-xz \
    --without-emacs \
    --without-lispdir \
    --without-cvs \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-java \
    --disable-native-java \
    --disable-c++ \
    --disable-libasprintf \
    --disable-openmp \
    --disable-csharp \
    --enable-threads=win32 \
    --enable-relocatable \
    --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32
make
```

Ao executar o make apos alguns minutos, tanto o make como o configure naturalmente levam alguns bons minutos para serem concluídos, recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
libtool: compile:  no -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DEXEEXT=\".exe\" -DEXEEXT=\".exe\" -DEXEEXT=\".exe\" -I. -I.. -I../intl -I../intl -I.. -I.. -DDEPENDS_ON_LIBICONV=1 -DDEPENDS_ON_LIBINTL=1 -DLIBXML_STATIC -DGNULIB_DEFINED_ERROR -I/mingw64/include/glib-2.0 -I/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include -I./libcroco -c ../woe32dll/c++html-styled-ostream.cc  -o ../woe32dll/.libs/c++html-styled-ostream.o
../libtool: line 1779: no: command not found
make[5]: *** [Makefile:3202: ../woe32dll/c++html-styled-ostream.lo] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/consu_000/workspace/workspace_ARM_Studies/qemu-delfino/gettext2/gettext-tools/gnulib-lib'
make[4]: *** [Makefile:2618: all] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/consu_000/workspace/workspace_ARM_Studies/qemu-delfino/gettext2/gettext-tools/gnulib-lib'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:2028: all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/consu_000/workspace/workspace_ARM_Studies/qemu-delfino/gettext2/gettext-tools'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1894: all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/consu_000/workspace/workspace_ARM_Studies/qemu-delfino/gettext2/gettext-tools'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:413: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/consu_000/workspace/workspace_ARM_Studies/qemu-delfino/gettext2'
make: *** [Makefile:369: all] Error 2
```

Já fiz diversas tentativas, e já recebi outras mensagens, mas esta é a que recebo na tentativa inicial.

O interessante é se queixar da ausência do comando no, desconheço este comando, e nas pesquisas que fiz no Google não tive resultados digamos saudáveis.

Onde será que está meu erro, e como corrigi-lo?

Comment: Acrescentando a título de observação, que consigo compilar o código usando o script configure na pasta gettext/gettext-runtime, portanto ficando o mesmo problema quando tento na psta gettext ou gettext/gettext-tool, será que este é o caminho certo?